# How to get right encoded output when using paramiko exec_command with cyrillic output

Tags: python, python-3.x, paramiko

I am using `paramiko` and `python-3.7` to connect to remote RedHat machine and execute a script on it.

My `python` code (it's inside of a class method with `self.logger` presented) looks like this:

import paramiko

```
client = paramiko.SSHClient()
client.load_system_host_keys()
client.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
client.connect(server_name, port=22, username=login, password=password, timeout=3) 
(_, stdout, stderr) = client.exec_command('/tmp/some_script.sh')
for line in stderr:
    self.logger.error(line)
```

If the executed script `/tmp/some_script.py` does not exist then in my log I receive next line:

```
2019-04-16 18:03:05,528:ERROR: bash: /tmp/some_script.sh: ▒▒▒ ▒▒▒▒▒▒ ▒▒▒▒▒ ▒▒▒ ▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒
```

while if I login to the server and try the command it will return cyrillic text:

```
-bash: /tmp/some_script.sh: Нет такого файла или каталога
```

The message means "There is no such file or directory"

I tried to replace the `self.logger.error(line)` line with `self.logger.error(line.encode('utf-8'))`, but the output looks like this:

```
2019-04-16 18:22:02,208:ERROR: b'bash: /tmp/some_script.sh: \xd0\x9d\xd0\xb5\xd1\x82 \xd1\x82\xd0\xb0\xd0\xba\xd0\xbe\xd0\xb3\xd0\xbe \xd1\x84\xd0\xb0\xd0\xb9\xd0\xbb\xd0\xb0 \xd0\xb8\xd0\xbb\xd0\xb8 \xd0\xba\xd0\xb0\xd1\x82\xd0\xb0\xd0\xbb\xd0\xbe\xd0\xb3\xd0\xb0\n'
```

What am I missing? I want the output to be cyrillic like from console.

Comment: @MartinPrikryl Thank you for the suggestion, but `line` is a `string` object and has not `decode` method. Anyway, I figured it out. I didn't specify the encoding while creating a `FileHandler` for `logging` module. Shame:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, the problem was not related to `paramiko`.
While declaring a `RotatingFileHandler` I didn't specify the `encoding` parameter.
I had:

```
fh = logging.handlers.RotatingFileHandler(
    'log/logname.log', 
    'a', 
    10000000, 
    3)
```

Correct line is:

```
fh = logging.handlers.RotatingFileHandler(
    'log/logname.log', 
    'a', 
    10000000, 
    3,
    encoding='utf-8')
```